# glibc's isalpha function and the en_US.UTF-8 locale

Tags: c, locale, glibc, utf

Short version: How does the C function `isalpha` work when the locale is set to something other than `C` (in other words, something like `en_US.UTF-8`)?

Long version: In reading a bunch of documentation about the `isalpha` function, it's not 100% clear to me how its locale dependent behavior works.  Specifically I've found docs [that say things like](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_4.html)

> In some locales, there may be additional characters for which isalpha is true--letters which are neither upper case nor lower case. But in the standard "C" locale, there are no such additional characters.

Additionally -- if I test this out with a small C program, I can confirm that `isalpha` will return `true`/`1` for values outside of the traditional ASCII text ranges when a different locale is set -- for some unixes.  This program seemed to do reasonable things on my BSD/Darwin based mac -- but it segfaulted when I tried it on an ubuntu box.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
        for(int i=0;i<INT_MAX;i++) {
           // printf() displays the string inside quotation
            if(isalpha(i)) {
                printf("is alpha numeric: %i\n", i);
            }

        }
       return 0;
    }
```

What's unclear to me is how `isalpha` knows which integers should return true when the locale is set to `en_US.UTF-8` and what those integers represent.  Is this just a hard coded list of utf code points in a range somewhere? Or something less direct?

I tried chasing this down myself but my pigeon-c was not up to the task.

I got as far as `ctype.c` and `ctype.h`.  If I dive into the source of glibc I see that the `isalpha` function is [actually a macro](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/99468ed45f5a58f584bab60364af937eb6f8afda/ctype/ctype.c#L27) that expands to something like this

```
int isalpha (int c) {
    return __isctype (c, _ISalpha);
}
```

`__isctype` [is also a macro](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/99468ed45f5a58f584bab60364af937eb6f8afda/ctype/ctype.h#L88), so we expand that out we have something like

```
int isalpha (int c) {
    return ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) _ISalpha) (c, _ISalpha);
}
```

And the [`_ISalpha` enum expands out](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/99468ed45f5a58f584bab60364af937eb6f8afda/ctype/ctype.h#L50) to a little endian bitmask, so now we're looking at something like this ...

```
int isalpha (int c) {
    return ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) ((2) < 8 ? ((1 << (2)) << 8) : ((1 << (2)) >> 8))) (c, ((2) < 8 ? ((1 << (2)) << 8) : ((1 << (2)) >> 8)));
}
```

and this is about where I tap out.

I have no particular goal in mind other than understanding how `isalpha` works.

Comment: `isalpha` has to be called on `unsigned char` value. It's just undefined behavior.

Comment: Effectively, yes, it's a hardcoded list - or rather a hardcoded lookup table.  The character is used as an index into a lookup table specific to this locale, and one of the bits of the corresponding entry is used to indicate whether the character is `alpha`.  The internal `__ctype_b_loc()` function is used by the library to fetch a pointer to the correct table for the current locale.

Comment: But note that setting the locale to `en_US.UTF-8` won't magically make things UTF-8.  `isalpha()` continues to operate on single-byte characters.  To handle multibyte characters, there's a whole separate set of "wide character" functions and types, and a corresponding `iswalpha()` function.  `iswalpha()` may have a somewhat more sophisticated implementation because a lookup table would be pretty big, but at some level there is still a hardcoded list somewhere.

Comment: As such, as Kamil says, by calling `isalpha()` on an int that is out of the range of `unsigned char` (plus `EOF`), you are probably going to cause it to read outside the bounds of that 257-entry (*) lookup table and likely crash or at least read garbage.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge -- do you happen to know where (in glibc? somewhere else?) those lookup tables ultimately come from?

Comment: For `isalpha()` the ASCII encoding made it simple. `'A'` is `01000001` (note bit-0 is `1`) for the next 25 characters, you simply increment by `1`. `'a'` is `01100001` (same scheme, but note bits 5 & 6 are both `1`, bit-5 being the lower-case bit for characters).

Comment: For Unicode, I think the source of the data is [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/unicode-gen/PropList.txt;h=7d2f44c56fab8d8d787a0f70bc1518866d6f567c;hb=HEAD).  It's used to generate the lookup tables, which (at least on my system) are written to a file called `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` and mapped into memory at runtime by the library.

Comment: @alan: On Linux (and similar systems), you'll find that you'll also get false positives outside of the `uint8_t` range if you use the `C` locale. In fact, they may well be the same false positives.

Comment: @rici Calling `isalpha(3)` and other `<ctype.h>` functions outside of `unsigned char` (a.k.a. `uint8_t`) range (or `EOF`) is Undefined Behavior, according to ISO C.  <https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1>.  These functions have effectively an `int` domain of `[-1, 255]`; any `int` outside of that range results in UB (that's assuming `EOF == -1`, which most of the time it is; to be more correct, the domain is `EOF U [0, 255]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the C function isalpha work when the locale is set to something other than C (in other words, something like en_US.UTF-8)?

The first 128 characters of Unicode represent the same as ASCII, so nothing changes (when C locale uses ASCII).

What really changes, is that instead of using a hardcoded list, glibc opens and loads the locale file. I believe that would be from `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` which should contain the compiled locale from `/usr/share/i18n/locales/*` files. In my `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US` file I see `LC_CTYPE copy "en_GB"` , I can go to `en_GB` which has `copy "i18n"`, then to `i18n` which has `copy "i18n_ctype"`, then finally to `i18n_ctype` file which has:

```
% The "alpha" class of the "i18n" FDCC-set is reflecting
% the recommendations in TR 10176 annex A
alpha /
   <U0041>..<U005A>;<U0061>..<U007A>;<U00AA>;<U00B5>;<U00BA>;/
   <U00C0>..<U00D6>;<U00D8>..<U00F6>;<U00F8>..<U02C1>;<U02C6>..<U02D1>;/
.... many more lines ....
```

> I can confirm that isalpha will return true/1 for values outside of the traditional ASCII text ranges

From [C99 7.4p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.4p1):

> In all cases the argument is an int, **the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char** or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

The loop : `for(int i=0;i<INT_MAX;i++) { if(isalpha(i)) {` is just undefined behavior for any `i` greater then `UCHAR_MAX`. Some programmers even do `isalpha((unsigned char)i)`. (I remember getting a warning in some cases when `is<ctype>(arg)` functions arguments was not an unsigned char).

> Is this just a hard coded list of utf code points in a range somewhere?  Or something less direct?

Yes, as mentioned above in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/*` files.

And the hardcoded list for C locale is stored in [locale/C-ctype.c](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/99468ed45f5a58f584bab60364af937eb6f8afda/locale/C-ctype.c#L326) and is meant to match [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01_01).

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk -- I appreciate the thorough answer.  However, I am having trouble understanding one aspect of it (the failure is mine, not yours)  

You mention that any argument  outside the bounds of an _unsigned char_ results in undefined behavior.  Would it be fair to say that some unixes ship with an `isalpha` that does things with numbers outside this range, but that this behavior is not portable and therefore it should be avoided?  (I'm thinking BSD specifically, per this compatibility section: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=isalpha&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd)

Comment: `/usr/share/i18n/locales/*` are the source files from which the locale descriptions are compiled. They are not consulted when you call `isalpha` (or `setlocale`, for that matter). The compiled locale files are normally in `/usr/lib/locale`, not necessarily as individual files (`/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` is the default archive file).

Comment: Thank you @rici -- that's useful information. Do you happen to know what isalpha _does_ get it's lookup table from?

Comment: @alan: The behaviour is undefined, and if it happens to produce the result you expected that is still within the parameters of "it could do anything". There are no guarantees that even the BSD implementation will continue doing what it does now, as the documentation indicates.

Comment: @alan: It gets it from the compiled locale file. When you call `setlocale`, the appropriate compiled locale files are read into memory and used by subsequent calls. On Linux, read `man 5 locale` and `man 7 locale`

Comment: @alan: Note that since `isXXX` only works for `uchar8_t` arguments, the data can be (and is) represented as a simple bit vector. The implementation of `iswXXX` involves a multilevel lookup (of three levels iirc), which is much more complicated. (Actually the data is a vector of bitmasks, where each character category has one bit in the mask.)